# how can I get the commit hash for a package installed via NPM from a git repo?

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, npm-install

In my package.json I have lines like the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-library": ""git+ssh://git@github.com/my_org/my-library.git"
}
```

This will always install the latest from the `master` branch of my-library on github.  What I would like is to be able to get the commit hash at the time this dependency is installed.  Is this possible?

Comment: Just add `#commit_id` to the git url...

Comment: @n00dl3 that will cause me to install the version at that commit.  I don't care what commit I install - I just want to install the latest, but be able to get the commit hash after the fact.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to get a manual hash of the tree and then do a linear search through the commits to find a matching tree hash. I'm not aware of a way to do this automatically though.

Comment: Might want to put more metadata into my-library.git itself. You might look at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version

Answer (score 1):

`npm list my-library` inside your package will give the commit hash like below

```
sample-project@0.0.1 /.../sample-project
└── my-projet@0.8.0  (git+https://git@github.com/mylibrary/mylibrary.git#fadsf8972qrjafds76d7aa30ee4d7671c)
```

and also when `npm install` is done from module that has dependency from git, `node_modules/my-library/package.json` will have a key `_resolved` which will give you the commit hash from which the module is installed.

it will look something like this

```
"_resolved": "git+https://git@github.com/mylibrary/mylibrary.git#fadsf8972qrjafds76d7aa30ee4d7671c"
```